# Chapters number moves out of margin

Tags: sectioning, margins, chapters

i'm new to LaTeX and got a problem.
The picture says it all... When my number of chapters exceeds 9, the second digit moves out of the margin....

[image: The digit 0 in chapter 10 moves out of the margin!!]

I have copied the following layout, for the chapters from the web to my preamble:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside,openright]{memoir}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{numbercolor}{gray}{0.7}
\newif\ifchapternonum

\makechapterstyle{jenor}{
  \renewcommand\printchaptername{}
  \renewcommand\printchapternum{}
  \renewcommand\printchapternonum{\chapternonumtrue}
  \renewcommand\chaptitlefont{\fontfamily{pbk}\fontseries{db}\fontshape{n}\fontsize{25}{35}\selectfont\raggedleft}
  \renewcommand\chapnumfont{\fontfamily{pbk}\fontseries{m}\fontshape{n}\fontsize{1in}{0in}\selectfont\color{numbercolor}}
  \renewcommand\printchaptertitle[1]{%
    \noindent
    \ifchapternonum
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{X}
    {\let\\\newline\chaptitlefont ##1\par}
    \end{tabularx}
    \par\vskip-2.5mm\hrule
    \else
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{Xl}
    {\parbox[b]{\linewidth}{\chaptitlefont ##1}} & \raisebox{-15pt}{\chapnumfont \thechapter}
    \end{tabularx}
    \par\vskip2mm\hrule
    \fi
  }
}

\chapterstyle{jenor}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{pdfsync}    
\setlrmarginsandblock{5.5cm}{2.5cm}{*}  
\setulmarginsandblock{2.5cm}{3.0cm}{*}
\checkandfixthelayout 

\begin{document}


\setcounter{chapter}{9}

\chapter{diskussion}
Test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test 
\end{document}
```

Does anyone have a solution or suggestion on what i should do?? If so, i would be grateful!

Comment: (1) Please provide a full minimal example, for example it might not be clear to people that this is a `memoir` question. (2) What should it do if the number it longer than 9 (in the MWE you can simulate 9 chapters via `\setcounter{chapter}{9}` placed before `\chapter{Diskussion}`.

Comment: (3) BTW, that version of `jenor` does not grow into the margin, so again please post a full minimal example.

Comment: Sorry, but i do not know how to make a full minimal example. I'm sorry for being a rookie, but i'm trying hard to understand most of the features in LaTeX..

Comment: See my answer-comment.

Comment: (1) Why is the inner margin so large? It is traditionally the outer margin that is the largest. (2) Do you really need the `pdfsync` package? No-one is using that any more because of the build in `synctex` features.

Comment: If you drop `pdfsync` it no longer sits in the margin as intended.

Comment: Okay, thanks! But when i remove the pdfsync, the digits aligns with the text-margin. Is it possible to move it closer til the edge of the page, without interfering with the text-margin?

Comment: That will require a tweak to the chapter style. How far into the margin? And why that large left margin?

Comment: So that the last digit is in the margin, similar to the first picture, i think.

Comment: I think the margin is that large so that the connection point isn't interfering with the text... maybe

Comment: The margin is chosen by you. Regarding the design in my opinion the title should not move no matter if the chapter number is single or double digits.

Comment: See my update. Regarding the left margin: What do you mean by "*is that large so that the connection point isn't interfering with the text*"?

Comment: Whatever else you do, don't load the `pdfsync` package. For one, it's not needed if you use a version of pdfLaTeX/XeLaTeX/LuaLaTeX that's more recent than ca 2008. And, as the package's user guide warns prominently, "pdfsync uses extremely sensible code. You should not use `pdfsync` on final documents because it can change the layout rather significantly (different page/line breaks are the most obvious changes) ..."

Answer (score 1):

This is just a longer comment. This MWE does not show up as in the picture, thus copy this and add to it so it shows your problem

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{numbercolor}{gray}{0.7}
\newif\ifchapternonum

\makechapterstyle{jenor}{
  \renewcommand\printchaptername{}
  \renewcommand\printchapternum{}
  \renewcommand\printchapternonum{\chapternonumtrue}
  \renewcommand\chaptitlefont{\fontfamily{pbk}\fontseries{db}\fontshape{n}\fontsize{25}{35}\selectfont\raggedleft}
  \renewcommand\chapnumfont{\fontfamily{pbk}\fontseries{m}\fontshape{n}\fontsize{1in}{0in}\selectfont\color{numbercolor}}
  \renewcommand\printchaptertitle[1]{%
    \noindent
    \ifchapternonum
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{X}
    {\let\\\newline\chaptitlefont ##1\par}
    \end{tabularx}
    \par\vskip-2.5mm\hrule
    \else
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{Xl}
    {\parbox[b]{\linewidth}{\chaptitlefont ##1}} & \raisebox{-15pt}{\chapnumfont \thechapter}
    \end{tabularx}
    \par\vskip2mm\hrule
    \fi
  }
}

\chapterstyle{jenor}

\begin{document}


\setcounter{chapter}{9}

\chapter{diskussion}

\end{document}
```

Note how this image using the posted code, does *not* end up as in the original image. So something else is going on.

[image]

---

How about this design

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside,openright]{memoir}

\usepackage{xcolor,kantlipsum}

\setlrmarginsandblock{5.5cm}{2.5cm}{*}  
\setulmarginsandblock{2.5cm}{3.0cm}{*}
\checkandfixthelayout 



\definecolor{numbercolor}{gray}{0.7}
\newif\ifchapternonum


\newlength\chapnumwidth

\makechapterstyle{jenor}{
  \renewcommand\printchaptername{}
  \renewcommand\printchapternum{}
  \renewcommand\printchapternonum{\chapternonumtrue}
  \renewcommand\chaptitlefont{\fontfamily{pbk}\fontseries{db}\fontshape{n}\fontsize{25}{35}\selectfont\raggedleft}
  \renewcommand\chapnumfont{\fontfamily{pbk}\fontseries{m}\fontshape{n}\fontsize{1in}{0in}\selectfont\color{numbercolor}}
  \settowidth\chapnumwidth{\chapnumfont 99}
  \renewcommand\printchaptertitle[1]{%
    \noindent
    % design only good for chapters in right hand pages
    \begin{adjustwidth}{0em}{-4em}
      \ifchapternonum
      % use this if the un-numbered placement should match 100%
      % \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{Xp{\chapnumwidth}}
      %   {\parbox[b]{\linewidth}{\chaptitlefont ##1}} &
      %   \raisebox{-15pt}{\phantom{\chapnumfont 99}}
      \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}X@{}}
        {\parbox[b]{\linewidth}{\chaptitlefont ##1}}
        \\
        \addlinespace[0.5em]
        \cmidrule{1-1}
      \end{tabularx}
      \else
      \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}Xp{\chapnumwidth}@{}}
        {\parbox[b]{\linewidth}{\chaptitlefont ##1}} &
        \raisebox{-15pt}{\chapnumfont \thechapter}
        \\
        \addlinespace[0.5em]
        \cmidrule{1-1}
      \end{tabularx}
      \fi
    \end{adjustwidth}
  }
}

\chapterstyle{jenor}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\begin{document}

\chapter*{diskussion}

\kant[3]

\setcounter{chapter}{8}

\chapter{diskussion}

\kant[3]


\setcounter{chapter}{9}

\chapter{diskussion}

\kant[3]


\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I have edited the the question and made a minimal example. The Error is in the codes: \usepackage{pdfsync}    
\setlrmarginsandblock{5.5cm}{2.5cm}{*}  
\setulmarginsandblock{2.5cm}{3.0cm}{*}
\checkandfixthelayout  - If i delete the package the digits move in, but i want them to be closer to the margin. Is that posible, without moving the margins for the text?

Comment: @Rasmus, see my comments to the original question. It is `pdfsync` that is messing with something that it shouldn't.